# Closed form solution to single layer perceptron

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-algebra

A single layer perceptron is easy to covert to the form:

```
A @ x = b

Where:

A is a matrix of shape (m,n), 
x is of shape (m), 
and b is of shape (n).
```

(Apologies if the shapes are transposed... in ML, the first dim is usually the y axis not the x due to row-major stuff, but I think in normal matrix math, the first axis is the x axis).

Can I use the moore-penrose approximation of inverses to calculate the OLS best fit approximation of `A`?

I suspect this is trivial high school linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it was high school linear algebra.

```
A @ x = b
A @ x @ x^-1 = b @ x^-1
A = b @ x^-1
```